# AJAX returning 404 not found

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

I am new to MVC and have been trying to generate a table from a list of objects but the ajax call keeps failing . Am i doing something wrong ?
Below is my controller code

```
     @RequestMapping(value="/PopulateTable",method = RequestMethod.GET,headers="Accept=*/*")
     public @ResponseBody ArrayList<ReportMetrics> doGet(HttpServletRequest 
      request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, 
      IOException {
      ArrayList<ReportMetrics> metrics=new ArrayList<ReportMetrics>();
     metrics=responseservice.getReportMetrics();;
     return metrics;
     }
```

My Jquery code  is

```
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $("#showTable").click(function(){
               $("div").css("border", "3px solid blue"); 
        $("div").css("border", "3px solid gray");
        $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/PopulateTable",
        success: function(data,status)
       {
        createTableByForLoop(data);
        createTableByJqueryEach(data);

       },
       async:   true,
       dataType: 'json'
      }); 
      }); 
      });
```

have the below dependency already

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>
```

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1nrU.png)

Also my URI mapping on web.xml

```
         <servlet-mapping>
         <servlet-name>SplunkPOC</servlet-name>
         <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
         <url-pattern>*.*</url-pattern>
         </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Post the error thrown ? also have added the jakson jar for serialisation !

Comment: So jquery cant find the url , In your @ controller have mientionned @ request mapping ?

Comment: this is my controller class

                                          @Controller
public class UploadController {

Comment: no i am updating the file index.html.

Comment: below url erroring out. its not resolving the pageContext.request.contextPath
http://localhost:8080/SplunkPOC/$%7BpageContext.request.contextPath%7D/PopulateTable 404 (Not Found)

Comment: post your request from browser's `network tab`

Comment: I thought it was jsp so I suggested `url: ${pageContext.request.contextPath}/PopulateTable`

Comment: Ithink the probleme is in the ajax req . please try in your jquery  `url: "PopulateTable"`, without adding slash

Comment: yes try  `url: "PopulateTable"`

Comment: yes . .just now i tried and it worked. why ? is it / adding my projectname automatically ?

Comment: the / removes the appName path so it'll be pointing to localhost/url
not localhost/appname/url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to change `url` like:

`url: "PopulateTable"`

refer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30185351/3425489)